# JSON undefined value type

Tags: json

I came across this JSON code. I noticed that it makes use of `undefined` value. Where can I find more information about this value type?

```
  tracks:[
     (         {
        codec:"h264",
        language:undefined,
        id:1,
        bitrate:785236,
        content:"video"
     }         ),
     (         {
        codec:"aac",
        language:undefined,
        id:2,
        bitrate:75969,
        content:"audio"
     }         )
  ],
```

Comment: Are you sure the JSON is valid? The parentheses (first noted by MuraliPrasanth) look suspicious at least.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.  Parentheses aren't permitted.  Neither is the literal `undefined`.  `undefined` is a value in javascript: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.9

Comment: are you sure that's JSON?  Looks like a snippet of an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) too me.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

- **undefined** is **not** a valid JSON value, even though it is valid in javascript.

  From [the official JSON standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)
  (ECMA-404, Section 5):

  > A JSON value can be an object, array, number, string, true, false, or null.
- For JSON, use **null** instead of **undefined**: `{ "something": null }`

Comment: If you want a value to be undefined, just omit it entirely from the JSON. That way, when you try to read it after parse, it will be undefined.

Comment: But that assumes you have full knowledge of what a response should look like. Which is fine if you're building both the server and client, but that is often not the case.

Comment: Sure. That isn't an optimal solution, just a workaround for when you (for whatever reason) must return an undefined value.

Comment: Good answer, sub-optimal solution. Null and undefined are not the same. If NULL is a valid value in your system then you should be able to communicate both that "Yes, I have a value for that, and it's NULL" and "No, I don't have any value for that". PHP, e.g. suffers from its lack of undefined in its optional parameters, where it's hard (maybe even impossible?) to see whether the caller explicitly passed the default value or didn't pass a value at all. I'd say totymedli's idea is better. If the client doesn't know what to expect from a response, it's not well prepared to handle it either.

Comment: A solution to client-side API discovery is introspection (e.g. HATEOAS or GraphQL). Much better than properties explicitly marked `undefined`.

Comment: Note that "just omitting a value from JSON" is not possible in the case of arrays. `JSON.stringify([undefined])`, gives you `[null]`, which is not a faithful representation.

Comment: @totymedli I want the value to be undefined because it represents a default value where no default is present (i.e. the value is required to exist).  If I omit it entirely it will mean that no such parameter is required or even exists at all.  If I set it to null, it will mean the default value should be null. Only *undefined* unambiguously tells me there is no default value.

Answer (score 6):

`undefined` is a special type where it simply indicates that the variable `language` is not initialized or may be it's not yet defined.

`null` in `javascript` simply indicates absence of a value, and it can also be used to indicate “no value” for numbers and strings as well as objects.The `undefined` value also represents absence of value, it is the value of the variables that have not been initialized and the value when you get from `object` property or `array` element that doesn’t exist
`undefined` is a predefined global variable that is initialized to undefined value.

`null` and `undefined` doesn’t have any properties or methods.In fact, using `.` or `[]` to access property or method of these values causes a `TypeError`.

Comment: Placing a defined value into a variable makes it not undefined. The only option is that an _undefined_ value was stored into that property or that that JSON was not generated automatically.

Comment: language-wise, "which is undefined" binds to either the entire previous sentence (if there's a missing comma) or to "language variable", not to "data" (which is further). You have been misunderstood, I believe.

Comment: although it would be useful in some cases to be able to say key:undefined in json as a method of implicit key removal when updating data stores. Many times the absence of a key is not the same thing as it having a null value

Comment: Lol why is javascript pre-formatted