# Response.json not showing fields with value undefined

Tags: json, node.js, express

Response.json not showing fields with value `undefined`

I'm implementing a node api to manipulate data in a Mongo database. Queries are giving me the right `JSON`. When I send that `JSON` to a React client, fields that contain `undefined` are not showing up. What am I doing wrong? Is there a work-around?

To narrow the scope of my problem, add the code below to a node server. The `console.log` will print the right output. It will for example include `status: undefined`, however, the `res.json` will not include any nodes with a value `undefined`.

```
app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
    let test = {
        document: "test",
        data: {
            products: [
                {
                    id: 123,
                    type: "smartphone",
            name: "Motorola Moto G",
                    instock: true,
                    status: undefined,
                    link: null
                },
                {
                    id: 456,
                    type: "notsosmartphone",
            name: "Samsung S7",
                    instock: false,
                    status: "burning",
                    link: undefined
                }
            ],
            length: 2,
            date_created: '20161015T09:15',
            status: undefined,
            person: {name: "Kathy", age: 30, cute: true},
            arr:[123,"abc",{"a":"1"},{"b":"2"},{"c":"3"}]
        }
    };
    console.log(test);
    res.json(test);
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Expressjs `response.json()` method [uses JS `JSON.stringify()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) method to convert object to a JSON string.

[`JSON.stringify()` explicitly removes `undefined` values from objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) whenever it is called as [`undefined` is not a valid JSON value type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14946821/429521).

You can use a [`replacer` function](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set) to explicitly override the `undefined` behavior and set values to `null` instead, so that they are returned on your response.

Example:

```
app.set('json replacer', function (key, value) {
    // undefined values are set to `null`
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
      return null;
    }
    return value;
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you Philip! I need to show the json exactly as it is stored in the database and I have no influence on how this data is stored. Is there a work-around this behaviour?

Comment: if "exactly as it is stored in the database" is with `undefined` values, then that't not gonna happen... as I said, `undefined` is a invalid JSON data type

Comment: Thanks again Felipe! I don't like this behaviour but now I at least understand what's going on... ;-) I'll use a replacer as you suggested as best alternative.

Comment: @schulz Nice, let me know if ir worked and, if it does can you mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: @PeterSchulz awesome! I am glad I could help