# Parsing or fixing JSONs with special 'undefined' values?

Tags: javascript, r, json, undefined, jsonlite

In addition to strings and numbers, valid JSON can contain special values like `null` and `false`

I need to parse a JSON generated by some API that also contains `undefined`. However, `undefined` is a [valid JavaScript value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14946821/5783745), but it is not a valid JSON value, and whenever I parse it it returns a *lexical error*.

#### Examples:

```
library(jsonlite)

# A string works
"[{\"Sepal.Width\":\"3.5\"}]" %>% fromJSON
#  Sepal.Width
#         3.5

# A number works
"[{\"Sepal.Width\":3.5}]"  %>% fromJSON
#  Sepal.Width
#         3.5

# null works
"[{\"Sepal.Width\": null}]" %>% fromJSON
#  Sepal.Width
#          NA

# false works
 "[{\"Sepal.Width\": false}]" %>% fromJSON
#  Sepal.Width
#       FALSE

# undefined does not work
 "[{\"Sepal.Width\": undefined}]" %>% fromJSON
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                      [{"Sepal.Width": undefined}]
                     (right here) ------^
```

#### Question:

Is there any (reliable) way to parse JSON containing `undefined` values? If not, what is the best approach to repair this faulty JSON?

#### Attempt:

I've thought about simply gsubbing `undefined`, but that is risky, since that word could easily exist in the JSON string values.

Comment: As `undefined` is not a valid JSON value you're unlikely to find a parser that will treat it as one. How are you getting `undefined` in your JSON in the first place?

Comment: @SymbolixAU there's a bug in some JSON I'm trying to parse, and it's causing the (invalid) `undefined` to appear in the otherwise valid JSON. I tried cloning the jsonlite source and making an adjustment so that `undefined` could be parsed as though it were boolean or `null`, but I didn't get too far. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305534/parse-json-with-undefined-value) is the source of the invalid JSON.

Comment: @user5783745 Your JSON generator most likely have the problem.

Comment: @Ḿűỻịgǻṇạcểơửṩᛗ I know. It's not my API though. I'm just trying to parse the response it produces (I cannot control the response and hence the validity of the JSON, I only have control over how I parse the response). Others have pointed out that the response is not valid JSON, which I fully understand. I think the best solution is to read the response as text and replace `undefined` with `false`.This is risky though, since it could change actual string values (e.g. if 'undefined' appears in the string values of the JSON).

Comment: Then unfortunately, the API itself is faulty. Can you please edit your question so it mentions the API and how it produces the undefined-JSON. Which API are you using?

Comment: @Ḿűỻịgǻṇạcểơửṩᛗ please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305534/parse-json-with-undefined-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nope.** You **cannot** parse a JSON with an undefined value; undefined is indeed a special value. In fact, `undefined` as a "value" must not occur in valid JSON, and is intended to mean "this key [in your case, `"Sepal.Width"`] doesn't exist." Instead, the API is likely faulty, where it is generating JSONs with `undefined` values.

The official source, [The JSON Data](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)
Interchange Syntax, states that

> A JSON value can be an object, array, number, string, true, false, or null.

The best remedy is to examine the JSON generator or API and why it generates `undefined` in a JSON. You can also manually or algorithmically repair the defective JSON, and check if there are any inconsistencies in your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I used `str_replace_all()` to replace `:undefined` with `:"undefined"`.

This is somewhat risky because it will cause problems if the string `:undefined` so happens to appear in actual string values in the JSON, but in my case it's (an imperfect) solution

```
str_replace_all(invalid_json, ':undefined', ':"undefined"')
```

Comment: That is a good approach. To verify such a solution, check all the occurrences of undefined and ensure your replacement does not cause any unexpected behavior. Do you think you are now asking "How to remove undefined values in  an invalidly generated JSON?"

Comment: @Ḿűỻịgǻṇącểơửṩᛗ I think so. Initially I was hoping there was some way of parsing the invalid JSON as some javascript variant (since `undefined`) is valid javascript, and then convert into valid JSON. But I do not think that approach is possible

Answer (score 1):

undefined values are not valid as mentioned in previous answers, but if you are in a situation where you have no option but to handle it... You can use a placeholder value when stringifying and parsing

```
export function stringifyKeepingUndefined(obj: any): string {
    if (!obj)
        return obj;

    return JSON.stringify(obj, (k, v) => (v === undefined) ? '__undefined' : v);
}
```

And

```
export function parseHandlingUndefined(json: any): any {
    if (!json)
        return json;

    let parsed = JSON.parse(json);

    const iterate = (obj: any) => {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
            if (obj[key] === '__undefined') {
                obj[key] = undefined;
            }

            if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key] !== null) {
                iterate(obj[key])
            }
        })
    }

    iterate(parsed);

    return parsed;
}
```