# Parse JSON with undefined value?

Tags: javascript, json, undefined

> **Possible Duplicate:** [Parsing or fixing JSONs with special 'undefined' values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304404/parsing-or-fixing-jsons-with-special-undefined-value/)

I would like to know if it's possible to parse something like
`javascript JSON.parse('{ "name": undefined}');`
generated by the API?

The above code errors.

Is there some way of parsing it? - my actual example is *much* longer (see [here](https://pastebin.com/98KGhTmf)), I just use the very short example for illustrative purposes

Note:

- [Here](https://www.seek.com.au/jobs?keywords=R%20"data%20scientist"%20?sortmode=ListedDate) is the page the actual JSON is from
- [Here](https://pastebin.com/bgZihV4U) is an altered version of the original JSON that replaces `Single Column Serp v3` with `Single undefined Column Serp v3`, so that a string value contains `undefined` (as a string), making any reliable gsub more difficult

Comment: first we need to understand why you want to parse it in this format ? Can't you get json data in proper format that is easily parseable. i think format should be what json needs it to be. If you want to parse this way only then you can't use json.parse

Comment: `undefined` is not valid JSON. So, basically, nope.

Comment: Use JSON5 library

Comment: I'm sure it is possible to parse, although it isn't valid JSON so you won't be able to use a JSON parser

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla would it help if I paste my actual example somewhere? (it's probably too big for an SO question)

Comment: @PranavCBalan `undefined` is not allowed in JSON5 either!

Comment: @user5783745 yes please paste it somewhere else that will help understand what u are doing

Comment: How can you generate it ? `let json = JSON.stringify({foo: undefined}); console.log(json);` outputs `"{}"`

Comment: @PranavCBalan I will start googling that. Can you give some sample code that works? Would it work on V8 (to complicate my question further, as I'm [attempting to parse the non-conforming JSON from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304404/parse-json-with-special-undefined-value))

Comment: You'd be better off getting the source application to generate compliant JSON.

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla [here](https://pastebin.com/98KGhTmf) is the actual JSON I am trying to parse (it's much longer than the very short example)

Comment: @phuzi : Oops you are right......

Comment: `str.replace(/"\w+"\s*:\s*undefined\s*,?/g,'')`

Comment: @PranavCBalan is that risky since, theoretically, 'undefined' *could* appear in the actual string values?

Comment: @PranavCBalan `{"value":"unfedined"}` may very well be a valid input and mean something different than "value is not defined".

Comment: @PranavCBalan I have updated the question with a pastebin link to the exact same JSON, but with the term ' undefined ' contained in an actual string value

Comment: @PranavCBalan it won't remove it but it will create something with the wrong value if `undefined` and `"undefined"` have different meanings

Comment: Try "undefined" in quotes rather than undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **cannot** parse a JSON with an undefined value; undefined is special. In fact, `undefined` as a "value" must not occur in valid JSON. The error might have happened on the JSON generator instead.

The official source, [The JSON Data](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)
Interchange Syntax, states that

> A JSON value can be an object, array, number, string, true, false, or null.

The best remedy is to examine the JSON generator and why it generates undefined in a JSON.

Answer (score 4):

```
let a = {"test": 1}
let b = JSON.stringify(a)
console.log(JSON.stringify(a)) // "{"test": 1}"
console.log(JSON.parse(b)) // {"test": 1}
```

whereas with undefined

```
let a = {"test": undefined}
let b = JSON.stringify(a)
console.log(JSON.stringify(a)) // "{}"
console.log(JSON.parse(b)) // {}
```

JSON.stringify with `undefined`

```
let b = JSON.stringify(undefined)
console.log(b) // undefined
```

If you try to parse `undefined`

```
console.log(JSON.parse("undefined"))
VM101:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
```

> Above error occurs as undefined is not valid JSON.

So to conclude, it is not possible to do that.

Answer (score 1):

### This is not a solution, this is a patch to a pretty significant bug!

You should fix/replace the lib that generates invalid JSON.

```js
const jsonLike = `{"key1": undefined, "key2": "with an undefined state, also dealing with \\"nested quotes\\""}`;

// find some placeholder, a sequence that is not included in the current json
let placeholder, jsonPlaceholder = "";

while (jsonLike.indexOf(jsonPlaceholder) !== -1) {
  placeholder = Date.now() + Math.random().toString(36);
  jsonPlaceholder = JSON.stringify(placeholder);
}

// replace the keyword with the placeholder string
const json = jsonLike.replace(
  /"(?:\\[^]|[^"\\])*"|(undefined)/gi, 
  (match, isUndefined) => isUndefined ? jsonPlaceholder : match
);
console.log(json);

// parse the JSON and replace the placeholder with the JS value
const data = JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => value === placeholder ? undefined : value);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets Say you have Object like below

```
Obj = {a:1, b:2}
```

And, if you try to access `Obj['c']`, the value will be Undefined.

**Undefined** means it does not exist. You don't have to mention `{name:undefined}`. If you leave it as it, it's value always be undefined unless you define it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have a Solution which I used in My Project : https://covid19info.web.app .

!!! *** U need to know the Actual length of data u have *** !!!

```
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "https://covidapi.info/api/v1/country/IND/latest";

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var jon = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                var on = JSON.stringify(jon)
                var varx = on.length
                var jsonp = on.substring(34, varx);
                var jsonr = jsonp.substring(0, jsonp.length - 2);
                var json = JSON.parse(jsonr);
                var total = json.confirmed
                var died = json.deaths
                var cured = json.recovered
                document.getElementById("countin").innerHTML = "COVID 19 (INDIA) Cases : " + total;
                document.getElementById("deathsin").innerHTML = "COVID 19 (INDIA) Deaths : " + died;
                document.getElementById("recoverin").innerHTML = "COVID 19 (INDIA) Recovered : " + cured;
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

I told u the whole functions cuz's it not so much important

Comment: I'm the author of the site from which you are fetching data.

Well, I was pretty sleepy when I had got that endpoint up and it's my mistake how the response is structured. I meant to have the date as a separate key and the results having the values directly.

By the time I saw this, the endpoint was very much in use and hence couldn't correct it. I'm working on getting the v2 of the APIs out soon which will have the correction in it. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Oh Thanks for Understanding It