# Deserialize undefined value with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Is it possible to deserialize strings that have value of undefined (without quotes)?

Running JsonConvert.DeserializeObject with default settings causes an exception

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: u. Path
>   'message'

Example JSON:

```
{
"name":"nameval",
"message":undefined
}
```

I try to deserialize it like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Record>(json);
```

With following data class:

```
public class Record
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Message {get;set;}
}
```

I assume such JSON value from the example might not be 100% valid, but I need to be able to process it.

UPDATE:

It is possible to parse this JSON with JObject and replace undefined value. But solution is not very elegant.

Comment: This is not valid JSON!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON undefined value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796751/json-undefined-value-type)

Comment: If you need to process invalid json then you first need to make it valid.

Comment: I have seen "JSON undefined value type", but I need a solution that can deal with undefined values in .NET ecosystem

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14946821/2807270), `undefined` is not a valid JSON value, so Newtonsoft is justified in not handling it.

You could write a custom sanitiser to find-and-replace `undefined` with `null` before passing it to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Record>`