# After cloning JS array using JSON.parse & JSON.stringify, why array's "undefined" value converts to "null"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, clone

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, undefined, 4, 5];
var arr2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1));
console.log(arr2);
```

Output of the above code will be....

```
[1, 2, 3, null, 4, 5]
```

Why it converts it's 4th value from "undefined" to "null"?

Comment: ECMA-404 (no joke, the standard of [JSON](https://json.org/)) does not know `undefined`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796751/json-undefined-value-type

Comment: Undefined is not valid json, so JSON.parse converts it to null. Then when converted back, since null ***is*** valid JS, it keeps the null

Answer (score 2):

Because `undefined` is a Javascript type. There is no `undefined` in JSON.

According to [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259):

> JSON can represent four primitive types (strings, numbers, booleans, and null) and two structured types (objects and arrays).