# how to send undefined value in postman?

Tags: node.js, postman

Is there a way to send something like this in postman?

```
{
 "a": [undefined, {"b":"ball", "c":"cat"}]
}
```

Postman gives a red underline under `undefined`. If I use the pre-request script to `pm.variables.set('undefinedVariable', undefined);` and use this, then my code is giving this error

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Invalid request payload JSON format"
}
```

Comment: TL;DR: Nope. You can send a null or other value that’s invalid on the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with node.js nor postman. `undefined` is not a valid json value even though it is valid in javascript. You **may be** able to use `null` instead

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14946821/6785908

> - **undefined** is **not** a valid JSON value, even though it is valid in javascript.
>
>   From [the official JSON
>   standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)
>   (ECMA-404, Section 5):
>
>   > A JSON value can be an object, array, number, string, true, false, or null.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define null in place of undefined as JSON doesn't handle undefined keyword. Example:
`{ "a": [null, {"b":"ball", "c":"cat"}] }`