# Is there a way to make serde_json handle NaN, Inf and -Inf properly/improperly (IEEE 754 Specials)?

Tags: json, rust, ieee-754, serde, serde-json

The official JSON spec doesn't support IEEE 754, and instead has its own convention of null (not "null") or normal numbers.

In many languages and use cases people ignore this and deviate from the spec to support IEEE754 floats.  For example in python

```
>>> json.dumps(dict(a = np.inf, b = -np.inf, c = np.nan), allow_nan=True)
'{"a": Infinity, "b": -Infinity, "c": NaN}'
```

The allow_nan defaults to True in this case.

Likewise in C# we can set the number handling to AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals to get the same behaviour

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonnumberhandling?view=net-8.0

So, how can we get rust/serde_json to do the same thing - is there a flag somewhere in serde_json to do this, and if not, what would be the simplest way to add this feature?  (I mean achieve this feature as a user, not by updating the serde_json source or forking it or anything).

**Edit**:  Following some of the comments, suppose we agree that JSON is at fault, is there a format that could be used in place of JSON, that fully support floats.

Alternatively, how could one implement a JSON valid alternative like using "Infinity" as a string.  As far as I know this would affect all other serialisations, so if you serialise the struct to BSON, CBOR, msgpack etc.

**Edit again**

So my own research has thrown up a couple of possibles:

- JSON5 apparently expands on JSON, while being backward compatible.
- There might be some magic trickery that could be done with serde untagged enums, but I don't know if this is true.  It seems that serde can try a sequence of formats in turn until one succeeds - is there a way to make serde_json FAIL if it tries to serialise a Special Float (which is, strictly, what JSON spec says it should do).  If so we could use this as a fall back maybe?

Comment: `{"a": Infinity}` is not JSON so using a general purpose JSON serialization library to parse this data is likely going to cause you problems. Having a standardized data format allows different applications to communicate with one another, if one application doesn't follow the standard, trying to break other applications in the same way is the wrong approach - fix the broken one instead. On the other hand, `{"a": "Infinity"}` is perfectly valid Json and you can easily create a struct type which is able to deserialize that JSON.

Comment: @user2407038 "trying to break other applications in the same way is the wrong approach" I wouldn't agree - the break here is that JSON doesn't support IEEE754.  So what we've ended up with is "official JSON" and "Defacto JSON".  What I want is a "Defacto JSON" serialization library for rust.  Most other serialisations support floats (msgpack, xml, BSON, so I don't think calling JSON broken here is that wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can *`serde_json`* be made to handle these special floats? No, because it adheres strictly to the JSON spec. However, [JSON5](https://json5.org/) supports these funky floats, and [`serde_json5`](https://docs.rs/serde_json5/latest/serde_json5/) faithfully implements JSON5:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let map = HashMap::<_, _>::from_iter([
        ("a", 1.0),
        ("b", f64::NAN),
        ("c", f64::INFINITY),
        ("d", f64::NEG_INFINITY),
    ]);

    let j = serde_json5::to_string(&map)?;
    let o = serde_json5::from_str::<HashMap<String, f64>>(&j)?;

    println!("JSON5: {}", j);
    println!("HashMap: {:?}", o);

    Ok(())
}
```

Output:

```
JSON5: {"a":1,"b":NaN,"d":-Infinity,"c":Infinity}
HashMap: {"a": 1.0, "d": -inf, "c": inf, "b": NaN}
```

Comment: This sounds like the right approach.  Are there any obvious gotchas someone should watch out for making the switch from JSON to JSON5.  YAML is also a superset of JSON, but has funky whitespace rules etc. I know this is quite subjective question, but is JSON5 pretty much drop in replacement?

Comment: Their site says that JSON5 is a superset of JSON and a subset of ES5, which seems like the perfect place to be to avoid “gotcha”s. The only way it might not be a drop in replacement is that when editing JSON5 yourself, editor support is probably worse than for JSON proper.

Comment: You direct towards serde_json5, but that appears to have <2k downloads and be a fork of https://crates.io/crates/json5.  Is there a particular reason or just what you came across first?

Comment: @Corvus Google did a little touch-up work — looks like at least one small bug fix, and also adding `from_reader` and `from_slice`. AFAICT original JSON5 crate has no way of deserializing from arbitrary `Read`, including files.

Answer (score 1):

It is [unsupported](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/issues/838).

The maintainer's answer is not entirely clear as I don't think serde_json exposes deserializer hooks through which you could add a fallback, and I would think the usual solution (`deserialize_with`) would be too late for that.

So you might want to ask for precisions, but at first glance it looks like you'd have to maintain a customised vendoring / fork of serde_json to support non-standard extensions.

Comment: Indeed, the solution of deserialize_with isn't specific to serde_json, so it would also apply when other serialisation formats are used, that do fully support floats.  It is indeed unfortunate the serde_json has declared this flaw a feature

Comment: serde_json implements [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), this is not [JSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259), it's no more *a flaw* that not supporting [`undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796751/json-undefined-value-type), or [comments](https://json5.org) is a flaw.

Comment: I meant that the flaw is to only implement JSON, which has the flaw of not implementing IEE754 - most nominal JSON packages recognise the flaw in JSON and extend this to cover floats because it is so useful.  The "flaw" I refer to is sticking to strict JSON, rather than JSON as used in the wild.

Comment: Yes I understood you meant that hence my examples. "Implement the format you're saying you implement" remains not a flaw.

Comment: Also, if I we are being picky, serde_json doesn't implement the JSON standard, because null is not Number, but Infinity is a number - the JSON standard doesn't say you should represent Infinity as null.  If serde_json were being "correct" is should error when it attempts to serialize NaN, Infinity, -Infinity, and if it did that we could catch the Result and replace it.  As you say, the lack of hooks makes this hard to fix.

Comment: The mapping of language values to JSON values has *nothing whatsoever to do with the JSON standards*. Your libraries can discard every value and make them all `null` for all the JSON standards care, it's perfectly valid JSON.